# Image with ':' in its name not showing in firefox sdk addon

Tags: javascript, html, url, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

In my firefox addon, I want to show a local image named "image with:-2.png" in an HTML page. I have tried the following code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="images">
      <!-- I am using Javascript's encodeURI function for encoding the URL. -->
      <img src="image%20with:-2.png"></img>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

but it says "Could not load image..."

After reading about URL encoding, I got to know that I need to escape ':' as well (encodeURI doesn't do that). So, I tried this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="images">
      <!-- %3A UTF-8 HEX value of ':' is the -->
      <img src="image%20with%3A-2.png"></img>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

but it didn't work either.

If I rename the image to "image with-2.png" & change the src to "image%20with-2.png", then it works fine.

So, my question : what do I need to do in order to show images which have ':' in their names?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really really weird... it seems like a bug to me.